# R Tibble for two filters: Percent complete and then missing values in another column of same row

Tags: r, tidyverse

The following code creates variables for 60% - Propose, 90% - Commit, and 100%  - Win in the "Stage" Column

```
ttv.60 <- filter(ttv, Stage %in% "Propose - 60%")

ttv.90 <- filter(ttv, Stage %in% "Commit - 90%")

ttv.100 <- filter(ttv, Stage %in% "Win - 100%")
```

This section takes Proposed 60% data and finds those that do not have a Project Manager assigned in the "Primary Project: Project Manager" column

Create a new tibble to display Projects without a Project Manager from ttv.60

```
ttv.60.no.pm <- filter(ttv.60, Primary.Project..Project.Manager %in% NA))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description. Also, please review the use of formatting tools for code, text, and quotations in questions. Finally, this kind of seems like it's copy and pasted homework based on the way it's phrased?

Comment: It's work. I figure if I can get the "misses" to pop out for me I could both learn and free up time for myself and escape Excel.  I structured the problem to be simple so I don't overwhelm myself so that is where the homework feeling comes from. In R for datascience there is a passage that says "filter only includes rows where the condition is TRUE; it excludes both FALSE and NA values." I think that is where my problem is at.

Comment: This describes a widely accepted compromise. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Accordingly phrased questions do deserve to be answered in the didactically valuable way described.

Comment: Describe the problem: I want to create a new variable that I can view 60% complete AND no project manager assigned. When I go from 60% I have 696 obs. of 41 variables and when I run ttv.60.no.pm <- filter(ttv.60, Primary.Project..Project.Manager %in% NA) it drops down to 0.

I have tried to switch NA with FALSE and %in% with ==

Comment: @Hack-R - thanks for the follow up. Related: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I'd argue this is required for all questions. Further, it's not really possible to discern homework from, for example, an analyst seeking to enhance ad industry spying; and as this example indicates, if we're going to single out certain use cases as undesirable, homework would be low on my list.

Comment: @AdamSmith Good quote and sounds right to me. I'd just say that it's nice to provide the proper citation guidelines, in case they *want* to do things above the board. I don't have delusions of policing abuse, just encouraging good practices.

Comment: Down vote because of no reproducible example and bad format. If the OP can improve the post, I may retract my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but at very least you may be able to use some of this sample data to improve your question.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
ttv <- data.frame(Stage=c("Propose", "Commit", "Commit", "Propose", "Win"),
                  Project.Manager=c("Bob", "Alice", NA, NA, "Donald"))

probabilities <- data.frame(Stage=c("Propose", "Commit", "Win"), 
                            Likelihood=c(.6,.9,1))

ttv <- left_join(ttv, probabilities, by="Stage")
ttv <- as.tibble(ttv)
ttv

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Stage   Project.Manager Likelihood
  <fct>   <fct>                <dbl>
1 Propose Bob                  0.600
2 Commit  Alice                0.900
3 Commit  NA                   0.900
4 Propose NA                   0.600
5 Win     Donald               1.00 

filter(ttv,  Stage=="Commit" & is.na(Project.Manager))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Stage  Project.Manager Likelihood
  <fct>  <fct>                <dbl>
1 Commit NA                   0.900
```

Please try to improve the question because people may be annoyed I even attempted an answer.